# How can I make my web fit perfectly in any smart phone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please take a look at the [link](https://johnny00520.github.io/Test.git.io/) with your smart phone, you can see that it's a bit off. I center everything and the web looks fine in Desktop but not in smart phone(I use iPhone 5S). Is there any ways I can make it like the desktop for any kind of smart phone? Is there any ways I can make it look like Gmail app that you can not scroll everywhere?

I have done all the adjustment like the following code in the head tag. But it's not working. Here's the url if you need to look up in Desktop: https://johnny00520.github.io/Test.git.io/

Thank you so much.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1">

<title>MindScribe</title>
<!--<meta name="description" content="An interactive getting started guide for Brackets.">-->

<!-- Maybe I need. Note that Android and iOS ignore media="handheld"-->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="handheld, only screen and (max-device-width: 320px)" href="phone.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 800px)" href="ipad.css">

<!-- media="handheld" trick for Windows Mobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" media="Screen">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="handheld">

<!--smartphone conpatible-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes" />
<!-- Home screen icon -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/static/images/identity/HTML5_Badge_64.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/static/images/identity/HTML5_Badge_64.png" />

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

Comment: "*you can see that it's a bit off*". Not for me - the site looks fine at a mobile width. Please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself, and **clearly** state **exactly** what the problem is.

Comment: *"Is there any ways I can make it like the desktop for any kind of smart phone?"*  No, and nor would you want to.  The whole point of the web is to adapt and flow to whatever device and conditions you're using.  Nothing is universal from browser to browser, device to device, and there's nothing wrong with that.  If you have some specific thing you want to fix, clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

Add to `body` the following CSS properties:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

**box-sizng** - The width and height properties (and min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not the margin.

**overflow** - to prevent the scrolling.

**padding & margin resets** just to clean up any extra space generated by the browser.

This will push your `#cursive` title up a bit, but you can bring it down with let's say (tweak to your benefit):

```
margin: 4em 0 1em;
```

You may chose to add the above inside a @media query for mobile viewport only or not, could be something like (tweak value to your benefit):

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* etc */
  }
}
```

[image]